# How to pass environment variable to kubernetes yaml deployment files using github actions?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, github-actions, azure-aks

Hi I am deploying kubernetes yaml files using github actions. For example I have below deployment yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment 
metadata: #Dictionary
  name: cepgateway
  namespace: "#{KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE}#"
```

In github actions I have different jobs like deploytodev,deploytotest etc.

In deploytodev I have set env variable as below

```
Deploy-Dev: 
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment: 'Dev'
    env:
      KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE: cep-dev
```

I have set KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE some value and trying to access in my deployment yaml as

> namespace: "#{KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE}#"

This doesnt work and throwing error

```
from server for: "Kubernetes/ingress.yml": ingresses.networking.k8s.io "cep-ingress" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:serviceaccounts:cep-ci-sa" cannot get resource "ingresses" in API group "networking.k8s.io" in the namespace "#{KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE}#"
```

May I know is this is correct way I am following? Can some one help me to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the [envsubst](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/envsubst-command) command in combination with the `kubectl apply` step, like:

<kbd>namespace.yaml</kbd>

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment 
metadata: #Dictionary
  name: cepgateway
  namespace: ${K8S_NAMESPACE}
```

then

```
export K8S_NAMESPACE="cep-dev"
```

so

```
envsubst < namespace.yaml
```

will print:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: #Dictionary
  name: cepgateway
  namespace: cep-dev
```

Combining it in a GitHub Action will be something like:

```
jobs:
  Deploy-Dev:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment: 'Dev'
    env:
      KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE: cep-dev
    steps:
        run: |
          envsubst < namespace.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```